# Show results grouped by value with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Problem 1:**

Looking to display some events GROUPED as follows:

Year
Month
event details here

The database has the following structure:

```
    event_year | event_month | event_day | event_name | event_description
    2013       | 11          | 08        | Name 1     | Desc 1
    2013       | 12          | 31        | Name 2     | Desc 2
    2014       | 02          | 14        | Name 3     | Desc 2
    2014       | 03          | 25        | Name 4     | Desc 4
```

I would like it to display as follows:

```
    2013
         November
         08/11/2013 - Name 1: Desc 1

         December 
         31/12/2013 - Name 2: Desc 2

    2014
         February
         14/02/2014 - Name 3: Desc 3

         March
         25/03/2014 - Name 4: Desc 4
```

**Problem 2:**

There are also past events on the table, and of course we only want to display upcoming events. How would I solve that issue? As of now, I managed to display all events, which works quite well, and I also figured how to sort them by year and months, but it only gives me a list of all events, but not grouped.

Here is the code out of the model:

```
    function getEvents($limit = 20, $offset = 0) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('events_posts');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->order_by('event_year', 'desc');      
    $b = $this->db->get()->result();
    return $b;
}

function getAllEvents() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('events_posts');    
    $b = $this->db->get();
    return $b;
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
    $events = $this->events_model->getEvents($config['per_page'], $from);
    $this->outputData['events'] = $events;
    $this->load->view('events/index',$this->outputData);
```

and my views page:

```
    <?php foreach($events as $event) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('events/view/' . $event->id); ?>"><h2><b><?php          
    echo $this->lang->line('Event:'); ?> <?php echo $event->title ?></b></h2></a>
    <?php echo $event->descriptions ?>
    <?php echo $event->event_day ?>/<?php echo $event->event_month ?>/<?php echo $event->event_year ?> a las <?php echo $event->event_hour ?>:<?php echo $event->event_min ?> horas     
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm curious: Why on earth do you have to store dates using different fields for year, month and day? Why not just a date field?

Comment: don't use three fields to store the date.  semantically it is a date, so store it as a date.  you will be in all sorts of pain validating the numbers are true and correct when you don't need to.  eg, what happens on the 29th february 2015? the  mysql functions can do all the work for you.  see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html   do you need to worry about timezones?  if so you need to use datetimes. for problem 2.  use a where condition.  ie where date > curdate().  eg. $this->db->where('`event_date` >= curdate()',null,false);